# register unique code per user - logic programmin using C

Tags: c, logic

I'm making a question of programmic logic using C. Simple architecture, using console.

I need register a user with your name and code. The condition is that is not possible to register equals codes.

I making in this way:

-> Register ´code´ (using `scanf´) 
-> I check to make sure the code you entered already exists

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct guy{
    char name[50];
    char code[15];  
};

struct guy vet[2];
int i, j;


int registerGuy(){

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){ 
        printf("Insert your name:");
        gets(vet[i].name);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Insert your code:");
        gets(vet[i].code);
        fflush(stdin);

        for(j=0; j<2; j++){
            if(strcmp(vet[i].code,vet[j].code) == 0){
                printf("Error. Code already registered.");
                break;
            }   
        }

    }

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        printf("Name: %s \n", vet[i].name);
        printf("Code: %s \n", vet[i].code);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    registerGuy();      

    return 0;
}
```

How I can make this condition?
Can't register equals codes to register each user.

Comment: Did you know that the behavior of `fflush(stdin)` in C is undefined?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No. I can't. I was orienteded that fflush(stdin) clean the console. All right?

Comment: If you were not taught that this was behavior specific to your platform, then you are being taught poorly.

Comment: So, what is the correct way to make what I want? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say because I don't really know what you want. But I suspect that you want to read a *line* of input. There are C functions that do that, such as `fgets`.

Comment: If the user insert two `code` equals, the system need says "error" and finish the operation. That's what I want do